# How to add the height of another object as margin with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I`m working on a small project of mine and I don't know why my code is not working. I tried

```
 $('.sidebar-title').css("top",$('.sidebar').height() + " px");
```

and also

```
var TH = $('.sidebar').height() + " px"
    $('.sidebar-title').css("top",TH);
```

Neither of those work.  I tried to alert TH to see if it has something in it, and it displays 82px as it should. What am I doing Wrong?

UPDATE: HTML code if it helps :

```
<div class = "sidebar-title">
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down fa-2x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "sidebar">
                        <div class = "inner">
                            <form class="searchform">
                                <label class = "searchlabel">Search</label>
                                <input type="text"  name ="search" class="search"/>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

and the default CSS :

```
.sidebar-title{
    position: absolute;
    padding:10px 30px;
    color:#fff;
    background: #ff5151;
    top:0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-87px;
     transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar {
      position: absolute;
      top:-100px;
       transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      width: 97.1%;
      left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't work as CSS doesn't work as you think it does.

Comment: We have no idea what you expect this code to do or what it is actually doing. `what am I doing wrong` isn't a proper problem statement

Comment: it's all up there.... sorry for the noob question.. i'm doing this as a hobby....

Comment: @BogdanConstantin try removing the gap in `" px"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sdcr:you must remove gap in `"  px"`

[online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6hz735o/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('.sidebar').height());                                 
    $('.sidebar-title').css("top",$('.sidebar').height()+"px"); 

 });
```

Comment: the gap is in the code of OP's question if you take a look. it's nothing to do with me :)

Answer (score 0):

`$('.sidebar-title').css('top',$('.sidebar').height());`  try like this

Comment: edit it to 'top' and it`s all done. Sorry for the NOOB question.